Get an image URL only using {{ drupal_image(123) }}
How do you output just the image path using Twig Tweak's {{ drupal_image(123) }} as per https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md
In Drupal 10 I want to upload multiple images and isolate the image url, alt and title seperately from the File Upload(image) field but Manage Display > Url to Image doesn't show alt or title in a field.html.twig template. {{ item.content['#item'].alt }} won't display alt.
Trying to get this code working in field.html.twig
{% for item in items %}
<div class="masonry-item">
    <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-centered-icons thumb-info-no-borders">
      <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">
        <img src="{{ item.content }}" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="{{ item.content['#item'].alt }}" title="{{ item.content['#item'].title }}">
        <span class="thumb-info-action">
          <a href="{{ item.content }}" class="lightbox-portfolio">
            <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></span>
          </a>
        </span> 
      </span>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

Thanks

Twig doesn't allow much processing by design. In Drupal 7 *.tpl.html files became a disaster to maintain when used as a PHP file with HTML, rather than an HTML file with PHP. Twig templates force disambiguation between the template (*.html.twig) and the processing, (.php). As such, if the variable is not available in Twig, you would implement a preprocess function on the template in a .module or a .theme file, creating variables available for use in the twig template. And to actually answer your question, I suspect there is not a method to get the image URL from that function.

Wrong tool, do not use drupal_image at all. Instead use the ...|image_style filter to get isolated URLs.

Gotta love the down votes with zero solution to provide. You'd think the File Upload field for images would make the link to the image easy to retrieve like it does the alt and title

So this string manipulation bush fix works for me using Manage Display > Image (instead of URL to image).
{% for item in items %}
{% set url = drupal_image(item.content['#item'].target_id) |render | split('src="') | last | split('"') | first %}
<div class="masonry-item">
    <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-centered-icons thumb-info-no-borders">
      <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">
        <img src="{{ url }}" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="{{ item.content['#item'].alt }}" title="{{ item.content['#item'].title }}">
        <span class="thumb-info-action">
          <a href="{{ url }}"
 class="lightbox-portfolio">
            <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></span>
          </a>
        </span> 
      </span>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

